# Number of insertions change on commit

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Say I have some unstaged uncommitted changes. I do `git diff --stat`, it gives `+x,-y` overall. Then I commit this. Now, I check again `git show <commit_code> --stat`, it gives me `+z, -y` overall. Why are `x` and `z` different?

Note:
I have not staged anything.  `git diff --staged --stat` gives me nothing in case you suspected.

Afterwards when I do `git reset HEAD^` and `git diff --stat` I get +x, -y.

This is very weird! :)

Comment: *Say I have some untracked uncommitted changes* This makes no sense. *Untracked* is a property of a file in the work-tree. It means that the file is not in the index (and presumably not in the current commit either). `git diff` won't show the file at all, and it won't be in the next commit you make. If you show (preferably via cut and paste from the CLI) actual Git commands—actual `git diff` and `git status` and `git commit` commands and their output—we can probably make sense out of that.

Comment: @torek it should be unstaged. Thanks I changed it now.

Comment: I'd still like to see an actual session. If you're on a Unix/Linux-ish system, set up a demonstration Git repository, run `script`, run your Git commands, and exit the `script` command, to get a file named `typescript`. Or use mouse cut-and-paste to grab the commands and their outputs.